# speed up iOS9 on iPad 4?

Tags: performance, ios

Ever since I've installed iOS 9 on my iPad it has been quite slow.

The network seems slower, for example Netflix often times out.  Chrome often shuts down, presumably because it is using too much memory.  None of this was happening on iOS 8, same device.

I've had this happen before, with an iPhone4, when installing iOS 7 on it.  I did manage to speed things up by disabling as much of the new features as possible.

Doing this with iOS 9 has not helped.

- I've gone to general settings and disabled Siri
- Spotlight Search - most of my apps are still enabled.  Would turning that off help?
- Notifications - turned off on almost all apps.
- No Twitter, FB, Flickr or Vimeo
- Almost all apps have Notifications and Background App Refresh turned off
- Most apps have Location turned off or at most While Using only
- Location Services/System Services - turned off most of them now, but that wasn't the case before.
- I've also removed a number of apps I don't use.

Is there anything else?  This tablet has become much less usable since iOS 9 and my hardware doesn't support much of the new iOS 9 features (ad blocking/multitasking), so it was really a waste to install it.

Comment: one thing I did notice was that my DNS entries had switched at some point from 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4 (Google's) to my ISP's DNS which was a lot slower.  Fixing that did help, quite a bit, with browsing, but my system remains sluggish at best.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if Low Power Mode has accidently been turned on as it decrases the processor speed and CPU speed of your phone, also this article should help you out - http://www.techbout.com/how-to-make-ios-9-faster-4510/

Comment: Quite a lot of good suggestions in your link which covers quite a bit more than just low power mode.  However, specifically, Low Power Mode may only be available on later models than mine, because it doesn't show up in **Settings**.  I've done the other suggestions and they seem reasonable enough.